# Django Custom Validators Not Working

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-validation

I wrote a custom validator, which will raise ValidationError if given field value is negative.

```
  def validate_positive(value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValidationError(
                    _('%(value) is negative number'),
                    params = {'value': value}
                    )
```

i added this to my model field via the field’s validators argument

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[validate_positive])
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[validate_positive])
```

But while creating object it's not raising any error if price is less than zero.
I don't know where i am doing wrong and i am new to django. 
I am using **Django 1.9**.
Please help me .

Comment: Validators are used for forms, not for creating an object. If you're creating an object outside of a form then you need to provide an alternative way to validate input.

Comment: @Sayse then how to validate input that is given to model fields ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Validators are used for forms, not for creating an object. If you're creating an object outside of a form then you need to provide an alternative way to validate input.

The easiest way to do this is to call the model's `full_clean` method before saving as shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
try:
    article.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Do something based on the errors contained in e.message_dict.
    # Display them to a user, or handle them programmatically.
    pass
```

This is similar to what would happen from a form, and would call any validators on your model fields.

Comment: so i have to override save() method to validate model .

Comment: @rock - No not really, because that would make you validate twice any time you use a (model)form. You just need to make sure you do validation before saving. make a `save_and_validate` method if you really want to

Comment: Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. So the validators only work when you are using Forms and Model Form to fill it.

You can validate the validators in the shell though.

```
python manage.py shell
>>>from app.models import Book
>>>Book.price.field.run_validators(value=<undesirable value>)
```

This would raise a validation error so you can be sure your validation is working.